# jquery pass id and value on input keyup

Tags: jquery

Im dynamically creating rows, but I then also need to pass in the id of the control and the value

```
function AddClient() {
    var uuid = guid();
    $("#clientList").append("<row><input type='text' placeholder='type to search' name='clientName' id='ClientName" + uuid + "' class='form-control' onkeyup='SearchClient($(this).attr('id'),$(this).val())'></row>")


            function SearchClient(id, term) {
        //do some lookups
        }
```

get error `(index):2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

My problem is `$(this).attr('id')`, any ideas what I should replace this with?

Comment: Does the error occur when *this code* executes, or when the code in the `input`'s keyup event executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
function AddClient() {
    var uuid = guid();
    $("#clientList").append("<row><input type='text' placeholder='type to search' name='clientName' id='ClientName" + uuid + "' class='form-control' onkeyup='SearchClient(this)'></row>");
}


function SearchClient(elemt) {
    id= $(elemt).attr('id');
    term= $(elemt).value();
    //do some lookups
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is possible you missing } on code.

You can "id" replace with another text for example;

```
id='ClientName" + uuid
```

replace with "clientName"

```
clientName='ClientName" + uuid
```

because you add custom attr to html.Call clientName attr;

```
$(this).attr('clientName')
```

Comment: Custom attributes may invalidate the HTML which is why HTML5 allows "data-*" attributes e.g. `data-client-name='ClientName...'`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe silly of me to suggest code refactoring but if you're just starting out consider doing this:

```
function AddClient() {
    var uuid = guid();    
    $("#clientList").append("<row><input type='text' placeholder='type to search' name='clientName' id='ClientName" + uuid + "' class='form-control' /></row>"); 
}
$(document).on("keyup","[name='clientName']",SearchClient);

function SearchClient() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var term = $(this).val();            
}
```

Pros: Single binding

Cons: Bound on the document, you may want to bind it on the table it's contained in instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, the problem your code has is the " ' " before `id` in keyup function.

```
$("#clientList").append("<row><input type='text' placeholder='type to search' name='clientName' id='ClientName" + uuid + "' class='form-control' onkeyup='SearchClient($(this).attr(\"id\"),$(this).val())'></row>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, use jQuery.  Remove the in-line code entirely and just add a single event handler for these elements.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[id^=ClientName]', function () {
    SearchClient($(this).attr('id'),$(this).val());
});
```

Then you don't need the inline code at all:

```
$("#clientList").append("<row><input type='text' placeholder='type to search' name='clientName' id='ClientName" + uuid + "' class='form-control'></row>");
```

---

**Note:** It's possible that you're mistaken in the debugging and that the error is coming from the code which appends the DOM elements, not the code executed therein.  Note in your code there is a missing semi-colon after the statement.  If the code in the question is a complete example, it's slightly malformed.